# Determine all triples (a,b,c) of positive integers for which ab−c,bc−a, and ca−b are powers of 2.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine all triples $(a, b, c)$ of positive integers for which $a b-c, b c-a$, and $c a-b$ are powers of $2 .$

Explanation, I realized that A power of 2 is an integer of the form $2^{n}$, where $n$ denotes some nonnegative integer, but I can't solve it as well

Comment: Certain it is that any correct solution has to include $\{2,2,2\}$ and $\{3,5,7\}$.

Comment: And $\{2,2,3\}$.